# How php process counts in server

Tags: php, process

I am new to this community and I am newbie developer. Please excuse me if I ask something wrong

I have a hosting which allows 50 PHP process. But my website has 10000 concurrent traffic at peak time. The hosting starts more than 50 process after 2000 live users and website starts giving 503 error.  I have set up a 503 page for user to request to refresh the page. It solved my problem in another way. But I want to fix it in the right way.

I have 8 dynamic PHP pages which create page as per database entry. All pages have around 6 include PHP file request. My question is how php process counts? Does it count one for a single PHP file or does it also count my included files. Please help me understand the PHP process clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A process is happening when the php interpreter has to run code.
It doesn't matter if it's included or not, the include does something like this:

a.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello ";
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php
include_once "a.php";
echo "World!";
?>
```

becomes

```
<?php
echo "Hello ";
echo "World!";
?>
```

Which is then interpreted as one big chunk by one process.

Even better: After the interpreter is done, the process is terminated, it doesn't need to stay active. The connection is handled on server level, the session is stored in a session cookie, there is no permanent "php-daemon" needed to keep track of everything.

That is why you only experience errors at around 2000 users, that is the time when user actions cause the creation of >50 php instances at the same time (opening a php page that needs to be interpreted) and that results in >50 running processes, thus giving the 503.

Comment: Okay thanks. You mean, when user request a page, server creates a process and ends this process after execution. If >50 person request same file at a time, then server will create >50 process and it will generate 503 errors. Is there any suggestion to handle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, you got it. Well besides from having more efficiency (avoid long loops, use memcaches instead of direct database queries) not much. With 10000 users you should have a better infrastructure that can handle those requests. You should consider changing your hoster to a more dynamic provider.

Comment: Thanks a lot Broco. What if I increase RAM of the hosting. I currently have 6GB of RAM. Will it help??

Comment: I don't know, if your RAM is full and your server has to use swap execution time is much higher of course but you should check that first. No need to extend your RAM if CPU or process numbers are the bottlenecks. You said your hoster limits the php processes, not the amount of RAM your service can use. The question is why would your hoster limit those processes? Usually you rent CPU time and RAM size, not process numbers.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Actually they charge as per CPU cores and RAM size basis. I will connect to them and update here. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Before you do, make sure you know what the bottleneck is. E.g. use `htop` to monitor CPU and RAM usage so you know what you need.